# Filtering by an aggregated calculation in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am learning Cypher using the Movies database from Neo4j. I am trying to find movies where the average age of the cast is < 40 years old, but it's not averaging the cast as a whole so I get duplicates of a title with different average ages.

I have tried two things: (1) calculating the difference between the release year and year the actor was born and averaging that in the same line, and (2) calculating the age and then using `WHERE` to find movies with an  average actor age of < 40.

My first approach:

```
MATCH (a:Person), (m:Movie)
WITH DISTINCT a, m, AVG(m.released - a.born) AS averageAge
WHERE averageAge <= 40
RETURN DISTINCT m.title, averageAge
```

My second approach:

```
MATCH (a:Person), (m:Movie)
WITH DISTINCT a, m, m.released - a.born AS age
WHERE AVG(age) <= 40
RETURN  m.title, AVG(age) AS averageAge
```

Neither works. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `ACTED_IN` relationship to connect each movie to its actors. There is no need to use `DISTINCT`, since the [aggregating function](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/functions/aggregating/) `AVG` in the `WITH` clause is automatically using distinct `m` nodes as the grouping key.

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie)
WITH m, AVG(m.released - p.born) AS averageAge
WHERE averageAge < 40
RETURN m, averageAge
```